# What part of CSS needs to be modified to make this work on i.e.

Tags: css, html

I'm working on a one page site, and I modified the html to have six sections. It works perfectly on all browsers except for internet explorer. It kicks me to in between the second last and last two sections (on the modified version with one additional section) I've tried taking off the js query, but that did nothing, which confirmed my suspicion that it was something to do with css. I'm very new at web design and I'm not sure what to adjust please take a look at the code below (this is the version without the additional section):

Html:

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="metro, free website template, beautiful grid, image grid menu, colorful theme" />
        <meta name="description" content="Metro is a free website template by templatemo.com and it features jQuery horizontal scrolling among pages." />

        <link href="templatemo_style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.localscroll-min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/init.js"></script> 

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slimbox2.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /> 
        <script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/slimbox2.js"></script> 

    </head> 
    <body> 
    <div id="templatemo_header">
        <div id="site_title"><h1><a href="http://www.templatemo.com" title="Free Website Template">Metro</a></h1></div>
    </div>
    <div id="templatemo_main">
        <div id="content"> 
            <div id="home" class="section">

                <div id="home_about" class="box">
                  <h2>Welcome</h2>
                    <p>Metro is a <a href="http://www.templatemo.com/page/1">free website template</a> for everyone from <a href="http://www.templatemo.com">templatemo.com</a> and it can be used for any purpose. Validate <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer" rel="nofollow"><strong>XHTML</strong></a> &amp; <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer" rel="nofollow"><strong>CSS</strong></a>. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus felis leo, feugiat sed porttitor sagittis, facilisis sit amet lectus. Aenean elementum tellus auctor dolor auctor luctus. Vivamus eu orci purus, ut vulputate nisl.</p>
                    <p>Praesent imperdiet mauris et lorem malesuada consequat. Proin nisl metus, faucibus vitae malesuada non, interdum sed felis. Sed ut turpis feugiat lorem faucibus dignissim. Donec magna tellus, feugiat vel fermentum eget, fringilla at metus.</p>
                </div>

                <div id="home_gallery" class="box no_mr">
                    <a href="images/gallery/01-l.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery]"><img src="images/gallery/01.jpg" alt="image 1" /></a>
                    <a href="images/gallery/02-l.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery]"><img src="images/gallery/02.jpg" alt="image 2" /></a>
                    <a href="images/gallery/03-l.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery]" class="no_mr"><img src="images/gallery/03.jpg" alt="image 3" /></a>
                    <a href="images/gallery/04-l.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery]"><img src="images/gallery/04.jpg" alt="image 4" /></a>
                    <a href="images/gallery/05-l.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery]"><img src="images/gallery/05.jpg" alt="image 5" /></a>
                    <a href="images/gallery/06-l.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery]" class="no_mr"><img src="images/gallery/06.jpg" alt="image 6" /></a>
                </div>

                <div class="box home_box1 color1">
                    <a href="#services"><img src="images/templatemo_services.jpg" alt="Services" /></a>
                </div>

                <div class="box home_box1 color2">
                    <a href="#testimonial"><img src="images/testimonial.jpg" alt="Testimonial" /></a>
                </div>

                <div class="box home_box2 color3">
                    <div id="social_links">
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/templatemo"><img src="images/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" /></a>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/flickr.png" alt="Flickr" /></a>
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/templatemo"><img src="images/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" /></a>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/youtube.png" alt="Youtube" /></a>
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/templatemo"><img src="images/vimeo.png" alt="Vimeo" /></a>
                  <div class="clear h20"></div>
                        <h3>Social</h3>
                  </div>    
                </div>

                <div class="box home_box1 color4 no_mr">
                    <a href="#contact"><img src="images/contact.jpg" alt="Contact" /></a>
                </div>

            </div> <!-- END of home -->

            <div class="section section_with_padding" id="services"> 
                <h2>Services</h2>
                <div class="img_border img_fl">
                    <img src="images/templatemo_image_03.jpg" alt="image" />    
                </div>
                <div class="half right">
                    <ul class="list_bullet">
                        <li>Maecenas ac odio ipsum donec cursus</li>
                        <li>Fusce risus tortor, interdum</li>
                        <li>Proin facilisis ullamcorper</li>
                        <li>Sed vel justo quis ligula</li>
                        <li>Ut tristique sagittis arcu</li>
                        <li>Maecenas ac odio ipsum donec cursus</li>
                        <li>Fusce risus tortor, interdum</li>
                     </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="clear h40"></div>
                <div class="img_border img_fr">
                    <img src="images/templatemo_image_04.jpg" alt="image" />    
                </div>
                <div class="half left">                
                    <p><em>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam mauris ipsum, pulvinar sit amet varius at, placerat ut felis.</em></p>
                    <p>Donec vitae tortor non ipsum tristique condimentum ac ac nulla. Etiam sagittis iaculis dolor ut euismod. Nam faucibus, risus at consequat malesuada, urna turpis sagittis libero, sodales hendrerit dui arcu et nisi. Praesent pulvinar, dolor id lacinia pulvinar, mi ligula tempor libero, et semper sem dolor et elit. </p>
                </div>

                <a href="#home" class="slider_nav_btn home_btn">home</a> 
                <a href="#home" class="slider_nav_btn previous_btn">Previous</a>
                <a href="#testimonial" class="slider_nav_btn next_btn">Next</a> 

            </div> 
            <div class="section section_with_padding" id="testimonial"> 
                <h2>Testimonial</h2>
                <p><em>Aliquam venenatis, quam a semper blandit, lectus mi convallis orci, ut dictum ante leo non leo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris placerat, urna in gravida rhoncus, mi elit luctus nibh, a luctus erat elit vel quam. </em></p>
                <div class="clear h40"></div>
                <div class="half left">
                    <div class="img_border img_fl">
                        <img src="images/templatemo_image_01.jpg" alt="image 1" />
                    </div>
                    <p>Fusce nec felis id lacus sollicitudin vulputate. Proin tincidunt, arcu id pellentesque accumsan, neque dolor imperdiet ligula. </p>
                    <cite>Walker - <span>TemplateMo.com</span></cite>
                </div>
                <div class="half right">
                    <div class="img_border img_fl">
                        <img src="images/templatemo_image_01.jpg" alt="image 2" />
                    </div>
                    <p>Fusce nec felis id lacus sollicitudin vulputate. Proin tincidunt, arcu id pellentesque accumsan, neque dolor imperdiet ligula. </p>
                    <cite>Jason - <span>TemplateMo.com</span></cite>
                </div>
                <div class="clear h40"></div>
                <div class="half left">
                    <div class="img_border img_fl">
                        <img src="images/templatemo_image_01.jpg" alt="image 3" />
                    </div>
                    <p>Fusce nec felis id lacus sollicitudin vulputate. Proin tincidunt, arcu id pellentesque accumsan, neque dolor imperdiet ligula. </p>
                    <cite>Danny - <span>FlashMo.com</span></cite>
                </div>
                <div class="half right">
                    <div class="img_border img_fl">
                        <img src="images/templatemo_image_01.jpg" alt="image 4" />
                    </div>
                    <p>Fusce nec felis id lacus sollicitudin vulputate. Proin tincidunt, arcu id pellentesque accumsan, neque dolor imperdiet ligula. </p>
                    <cite>Katey - <span>KoFlash.com</span></cite> 
                </div>

                <a href="#home" class="slider_nav_btn home_btn">home</a> 
                <a href="#services" class="slider_nav_btn previous_btn">Previous</a>
                <a href="#contact" class="slider_nav_btn next_btn">Next</a> 
            </div> 
            <div class="section section_with_padding" id="contact"> 
                <h2>Contact</h2> 
                <div class="half left">
                    <h4>Quick Contact Form</h4>
                    <p>Nullam a tortor est, congue fermentum nisi. Maecenas nulla nulla, eu volutpat euismod, scelerisque ut dui.</p>
                    <div id="contact_form">
                        <form method="post" name="contact" action="#contact">
                            <div class="left">
                                <label for="author">Name:</label> <input name="author" type="text" class="input_field" id="author" maxlength="40" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="right">                           
                                <label for="email">Email:</label> <input name="email" type="text" class="input_field" id="email" maxlength="40" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                            <label for="text">Message:</label> <textarea id="text" name="text" rows="0" cols="0"></textarea>
                            <input type="submit" class="submit_btn float_l" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send" />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="half right">
                    <h4>Mailing Address</h4>
                    460-820 Duis lacinia dictum, <br />
                    Vestibulum auctor, 12650<br />
                    Nam rhoncus, diam a mollis<br />
                    <strong>Email: info[ at ]companyname[ dot ]com</strong><br />

                    <div class="clear h20"></div>
                    <div class="img_nom img_border"><span></span>

                    <iframe width="320" height="240" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Central+Park,+New+York,+NY,+USA&amp;aq=0&amp;sll=14.093957,1.318359&amp;sspn=69.699334,135.263672&amp;vpsrc=6&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=Central+Park,+New+York,+NY,+USA&amp;ll=40.778265,-73.96988&amp;spn=0.033797,0.06403&amp;t=m&amp;output=embed"></iframe>

                </div>
                <a href="#home" class="slider_nav_btn home_btn">home</a> 
                <a href="#testimonial" class="slider_nav_btn previous_btn">Previous</a>

            </div> 
        </div> 
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="templatemo_footer">
        Copyright © 2072 <a href="#">Your Company Name</a> | Designed by <a href="http://www.templatemo.com" target="_parent">Free CSS Templates</a>
    </div>

    </body> 
    </html>
```

CSS:

```
body{ 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #ddd;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.6em; 
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    background-color: #000;
}

a, a:link, a:visited { color: #9CF; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none }
a:hover { color: #FF6; text-decoration: none; }

ul, li {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { color: #fff; font-weight: normal; }
h1 { font-size: 58px; margin: 0 0 30px; padding: 5px 0 }
h2 { font-size: 34px; margin: 0 0 30px; padding: 5px 0 }
h3 { font-size: 20px; margin: 0 0 20px; padding: 0; }
h4 { font-size: 16px; margin: 0 0 15px; padding: 0; }
h5 { font-size: 14px; margin: 0 0 10px; padding: 0;  }
h6 { font-size: 12px; margin: 0 0 5px; padding: 0; font-weight: 700 }

p { padding: 0; margin: 0 0 15px 0 }

.clear{
    clear:left;
}

cite { font-weight: bold; color:#fff; }
cite a, cite a:link, cite a:visited  { font-size: 12px; text-decoration: none; font-style: normal }
cite span { font-weight: 400; color: #ccc; }


.list_bullet { margin: 0 0 10px 15px; padding: 0; list-style: none }
.list_bullet li { color:#fff; margin: 0 0 7px 0; padding: 0 0 0 20px; background: url(images/templatemo_list.png) no-repeat scroll 0 6px  }
.list_bullet li a { color: #fff; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none }
.list_bullet li a:hover { color: #fff }

.no_bullet { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none }
.no_bullet li { margin: 0 0 20px 0; padding: 0 }
a.header { display: block; font-weight: 700 }

.half { width: 370px }

.h20 { height: 20px }
.h40 { height: 40px }

img { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none }
.img_border { background: #fff; padding: 4px; border: 1px solid #ccc }
.img_nom { display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 15px }
.img_fl { float: left; margin: 3px 15px 5px 0 }
.img_fr { float: right; margin: 3px 0 5px 15px }

.left { float: left }
.right { float: right }

#templatemo_header {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 30px 0;
}

#templatemo_main {
    width: 800px;
    height: 487px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#templatemo_footer {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px 0;
    text-align: right
}

#site_title { display: block }
#site_title a { color: #fff; font-weight: 700; letter-spacing: 10px; line-height: 30px }

#content{
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 7000px;
    position:relative;
    height: 487px;
}

.section {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width: 800px;
    height: 487px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.section a.slider_nav_btn { position: absolute; top: 0; width: 50px; height: 46px; display: block; background-image: url(images/slider_nav_btn.jpg);  text-indent: -10000px }
.section a.home_btn { right: 50px; background-position: 102px 0 }
.section a.previous_btn { right: 100px; background-position: 0 0 }
.section a.next_btn { right: 0px; background-position: 50px 0 }

.box { float: left; margin: 0 10px 10px 0 }
#home_about { width: 314px; height: 314px }
#home_gallery { width: 476px; height: 314px }
.home_box1 { width: 152px; height: 152px }
.home_box2 { width: 314px; height: 152px }
.color1 { background: #d0b500 }
.color2 { background: #c75000 }
.color3 { background: #00afce }
.color4 { background: #a4c700 }
#home_gallery a { display: block; float: left; width: 152px; height: 152px; margin: 0 10px 10px 0 }
#home_gallery a.no_mr { margin-right: 0 }

#social_links {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 40px 0 0 0
}
#social_links a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    margin-left: 12px
}

#gallery {

}

#gallery li {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    width: 152px;
    height: 245px;
    background: none;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
#gallery li a {
    display: block;
}
#gallery li a img  { }

#gallery li.no_margin_right { margin-right: 0 }

#contact_form { padding: 0; width: 330px }

#contact_form form { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }

#contact_form form .input_field { width: 150px; padding: 5px; color: #CCC; border: 1px solid #666;  background: #222; margin-bottom: 10px; }

#contact_form form label { display: block;font-size: 11px }

#contact_form form textarea { 
    clear: both; 
    width: 320px; height: 120px; 
    padding: 5px; 
    color: #CCC;
    border: 1px solid #666; 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    background: #222; 
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#contact_form form .submit_btn { font-size: 12px; background: #333; color: #CCC; cursor:pointer; border: 1px solid #666; padding: 5px 10px; }

.no_mr { margin-right: 0 }
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is either here:

```
 #templatemo_main {
        width: 800px;
        height: 487px;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

or here:

```
#content{
        overflow:hidden;
        width: 7000px;
        position:relative;
        height: 487px;
    }
```

I'm not sure what to adjust and any help would be appreciated a lot!

PS: I'm new to stack over flow and I don't know if this is the type of questions you're supposed to be asking. Please let me know if it isn't ! :)

Answer (score 0):

As the support of CSS3 in IE10 is good enough, I guess you're testing your site against old versions of that browser.

There is a lot of css elements that won't work on old IE versions. I suggest you use some library like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/%20%22Modernizr) to get a little more compatibility.

Your code is too extensive for the little info you provide. What's the exact error you're observing? But taking a fast look I see some "display: inline-block;" that certainly may not work. You should try the combination of "float: left;" with "display: block" and a given width for those elements.

If you specify a bit more the exact error you're finding, so we can point ourselves on the relevant part of the code, maybe you could get more help.